# Remove everything but number,'-' sign and period

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number like "-12.5 Million" and I want to convert it to "-12.5" using regex in javascript.
I am doing this as

```
var str="-12.5 Million";
var result=str.replace("[^0-9\.-]", "");
alert(result);
```

But I am getting string unchanged. can anyone help???

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy80chzL/) I have created.
Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instance literal (not just some string) to replace method and use global modifier `g`:

```js
var str = "-12.5 Million";
var result = str.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, "");
alert(result);
```

But you don't really need regexp in this case, you can simply use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) method as it will stop parsing string after finding the first non-numeric character:

> parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters.

So you can do:

```js
alert( parseFloat("-12.5 Million") );
```

---

Comment: just you should know, when you use `parseFloat` you get a number and not a string, if it makes any different to you.